# Move 'Path' element in svg

Tags: html, css, svg, path

so i was trying to make a graph and animate it.
the y axis numbers must move from left to the graph as for the x axis the numbers must flow from the bottom to the axis.

`html,css`https://codepen.io/achillesalama/pen/XWaJywG

so basically everything is working except for the class xNumbers, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `offset path` is the wrong choice here.  Elements follow the path, and will rotate to match the direction of the path.  Your X animation is using a vertical path. So what is happening is that your text is being rotated so it is vertical, and is moving off the top of the screen.

The Y axis wasn't affected because the path was horizontal, just like the text.

You really only need to use `offset-path` if you want an element to follow a complicated path around the page. For simple vertical and horizontal moves like this, it makes more sense just to use a simple transform.

```
.xNumbers{
  transform: translate(0, 50px);
  animation: movex 2s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes movex {
  from{
    transform: translate(0, 50px);
  }
  to{
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much for the reply